# Word VBA Regex replacement text inserted to wrong place

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, regex, macros

I have a Word template with a macro that makes text replacements. But it pastes the replacement text to the wrong place. However, using the Word Search/Replace function manually (Ctrl + H; "Use wildcards" option checked) gives perfect results using the same search and replacement text.
Applicable code part:

```
With Selection.find
.Text = find
.Replacement.Text = replace
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchByte = False
.CorrectHangulEndings = True
.HanjaPhoneticHangul = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchFuzzy = False
.MatchWildcards = True
Selection.find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

The search text: `Ne ([1-9])`

The replacement text: `NeverMind \1`

Manual replace result: `NeverMind 1:2`

Macro replace result: `NeverM1ind :2`

Could you please help out, what goes wrong?

Comment: Please give sample text and expected result.

Comment: Sample text: "Ne 1:2". Expected result: "NeverMind 1:2"

Comment: We need to see an example document. Upload it to a cloud server (Dropbox, OneDrive etc).

Comment: For confidentiality reasons, I cannot upload the full template with all macros. :( but even in a document where just the sample text appears, it creates this behavior.

Comment: I executed your code and it works as expected -- [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Woe.gif).

Comment: Many thanks, Reddy! Weird. Any ideas why the code runs differently in my environment? Windows or Office updates? Clipboard handling (not sure how can this be different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for commenting on this. It seems this behavior is connected to a known Microsoft bug: Wildcard Find and Replace with Track Changes.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/wildcard-find-and-replace-with-track-changes/cd35b715-f539-4d0b-902d-7f977dcf67e5